# Show hide payment Method Field

Tags: magento2

I have Created custom payment method i have 3 field in my payment method

1 - Vendor list(drop-down)
in the drop down all vendor list show and there is also an option other if customer select other in vendor list i want show 2 more fields

Vendor name 
Voucher code

if customer select vendor name from drop down list then just voucher code field will display

Note: initially both field will be hide now how i can achieve this

```
        <div class="control">
            <select name="payment[transaction_result]"
                    class="select"
                    data-bind="
                              options: getTransactionResults(),
                              optionsValue: 'value',
                              optionsText: 'transaction_result',
                              optionsCaption: $t('Select A Learning Vendor'),
                              value: transactionResult">
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```